# How to keep selected by default a specific check box on list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of check box in my dataTable and i want always keep the last checkbox item select by default

```js
return '<div class="form-check">'
 + '<label class="form-check-label">'
 + '<input type="radio" name="check-box-product" class="form-check-input"  "value="' + row.id + '" > '
 + '<span class="product-name">' + data + '</span>&nbsp;<a href="' + row.url + '" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-external-link"></i>'
 + '</a>&nbsp;'
 + '<a href= "/Product/SearchCompetitorProducts?productId=' + row.id + '&businessId=' + row.businessId
 + '" target="_blank" title="Executar busca de produtos concorrentes">'
 + '</a>'
 + elementMatchFail
 + elementStatusSearch + '<small>'
 + row.competitorBusinessAlreadyBind + '</small></label></div >';
```

[demo picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kswJD.png)

Comment: Where are you returning this? in a function? Can you paste this function full code?

Comment: is a DataTable, i get from the return api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming this is a render function:

```
"render": function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
  var table = $('#datatableId').DataTable();
  var numOfRows = table.data().count();
  var checked = '';
  if (meta.row == numOfRows - 1) {
    checked = 'checked="checked"';
  }
  return '<div class="form-check">'
    + '<label class="form-check-label">'
    + '<input type="radio" name="check-box-product" ' + checked + ' class="form-check-input"  "value="' + row.id + '" > '
    + '<span class="product-name">' + data + '</span>&nbsp;<a href="' + row.url + '" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-external-link"></i>'
    + '</a>&nbsp;'
    + '<a href= "/Product/SearchCompetitorProducts?productId=' + row.id + '&businessId=' + row.businessId
    + '" target="_blank" title="Executar busca de produtos concorrentes">'
    + '</a>'
    + elementMatchFail
    + elementStatusSearch + '<small>'
    + row.competitorBusinessAlreadyBind + '</small></label></div >';
},
```

Comment: It is a parameter that the render function accepts, see datatables documentations on render https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render (Search for "Parameters" on that page)